# SQLITE3 Inserting data on wrong row

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, sqlite3-python

So, creating a web scraping for the first time. After reaching positive results, it should write it on a sqlite3. The thing is: for some reason it skips a row on the second column. I tryed many changes but have no clue on the fix.

**Code to web screaping:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from sqlprocessos import get_numproc, insert_data

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless=new")



def get_process_date(url, process):
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--headless=new")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    print(url)
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.switch_to.frame('mainframe')

    iframe_content = driver.page_source

    soup = BeautifulSoup(iframe_content, 'html.parser')

    body_element = soup.find('app-movimento')
    possibel_mov = ['Data da juntada: ', 'Data de recebimento: ', 'Data de remessa: ', 'Data do trânsito: ', 'Data de arquivamento: ', 'Data da conclusão: ', 'Data: ', 'Data de devolução: ']
    possibel_desc =['Juiz: ', 'Descrição da Juntada: ', 'Descrição', 'Tipo de arquivamento: ', 'Descrição: ']
    data_da_juntada = ''
    descricao_da_juntada = ''
 
    def get_data(possible_mov):
        data_da_juntada = soup.find('label', text= possibel_mov).find_next('label').text.strip()
        print(f"Data: {data_da_juntada}")
        return data_da_juntada
    for i in possibel_mov:
       try:
            data = get_data(i)
            if type(data) == str:
                insert_data("p" + str(process).replace('-','').replace('.',''),data,descricao_da_juntada)
                    
       except Exception as e:
            pass
        
    
    def get_descricao(possible_desc):
        descricao_da_juntada = soup.find('label', text= possibel_desc).find_next('label').text.strip()
        print(f"{possibel_desc}: {descricao_da_juntada}")
        return descricao_da_juntada
    for d in possibel_desc:
        try:
            data = get_descricao(d)
            if type(data) == str:
                insert_data("p" + str(process).replace('-','').replace('.',''),data_da_juntada,data)
                
            print(get_descricao(d))
            
        except Exception as e:
            pass

    driver.switch_to.default_content()
    driver.quit()


base_url = 'https://www3.tjrj.jus.br/consultaprocessual/#/consultapublica?numProcessoCNJ='


num_procs = get_numproc()
for num in num_procs:
    url = base_url + num
    get_process_date(url, num)
    time.sleep(5)
```

**Function to write it**

```
def insert_data(tabela, data, descricao):
comando = f'INSERT INTO {tabela} (DATA, MOVIMENTO) VALUES (?, ?)'
valores = (data, descricao)
cursor.execute(comando,valores)
print(cursor)
conexao.commit()
```

**Results:**

[image]

Any tips on the subject? I know the code isn`t pretty, but should work

Comment: does it matter that the order of parameters you pass is different between the two calls you make to `insert_data()`?

Comment: i dont think so. For the purpose of the data, seens correct. Do you think it should be the problem cause?

Comment: You sure? one time you do `insert_data("<table_name>", data, descricao_da_juntada)
`, the next you do `insert_data("<table_name>", data_da_juntada, data)`

Comment: the biggest mistake is `except Exception as e: pass`. You may get some error which makes all your problem and you don't know it. And maybe this error could explain everything. You should at least display error `except Exception as e: print(e)`

Comment: @JonSG yes. The order is different because the second insert_data() puts the scraping data on the second column. I changed, just to verify, and indeed the data was submited on the first  column

Comment: @furas it just prints: ['Juiz: ', 'Descrição da Juntada: ', 'Descrição', 'Tipo de arquivamento: ', 'Descrição: ']: Documento eletrônico juntado de forma automática. 
And: <sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x000001817A8E9BC0>

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem was on the two for loops. If included in only one for loop, it works properly.

```
data2 = ''
for i in possivel_mov:
   try:
        data = get_data(i)
        if type(data) == str:
            for d in possivel_desc:
                try:
                    data2 = get_descricao(d)
                    if type(data2) == str:
                           insert_data("p" + str(process).replace('-','').replace('.',''),data,data2)
                except Exception as e:
                    pass
            #insert_data("p" + str(process).replace('-','').replace('.',''),data,descricao_da_juntada)
            
   except Exception as e:
        pass
```